# Using the same comment as Moderator to improve posts

Tags: discussion

For many low-quality questions, moderators use the following standard comments:

"We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. "

or

"Don't use images as the main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics. You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands). Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!"

Can the other users who are not moderators, copy and paste the same comments to improve the low-quality posts? since it is difficult to write a new comment again, and these comments encapsulate all the details.
It won't count as "plagiarised" or "unethical" to use the same comment, right? (just worried)

It will also help reduce the moderator's work.

Comment: As a side-remark, I noticed you have been quite active in the comments below questions as of late. Thanks! It is hard to ask a good question on CS.SE, and helping in the comments is important in order to get questions that adhere to CS.SE's standards.

Comment: You're welcome. And, thanks to you and others for keeping and maintaining this wonderful place alive. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! Please do so! CS.SE (and other sites in the network) are supposed to be moderated by all of its users, once they have gained the trust to do so (measured in reputation) [See this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/627/reference-templates-for-common-comments) for a list of common comments used by diamond moderators as myself and "ordinary" user moderators/curators alike.

Plagiarism is only relevant when posting "work", so I'd argue it is not relevant when guiding other users with comments, and it also does not apply when the text has been shared with you in order to be copied, as above.

If you have some comments of your own that would be of use to others, please edit a relevant answer on the list in the previous page, or add a new answer.