# Project topic and course selection questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, close-reasons, comments

With the new university semester starting, we've had a small flurry of questions asking about course selection and suggestions for project topics ([1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35807/9550), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35833/9550), [3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35858/9550)). This is by no means overwhelming the site and the ordinary mechanisms for closing bad questions are doing just fine.

But should we have a [standard comment](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/627/9550) for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this for a template?

```
Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for
the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively
correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have
the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for
study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends
crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing and
the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you
should be asking your professors.
```

> Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for
>       the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively
>       correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have
>       the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for
>       study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends
>       crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing and
>       the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you
>       should be asking your professors.

Comment: Since nobody objected, I added this to our [collection of templates](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/627/reference-templates-for-common-comments).