# Question ban warning, while I have never asked a question on CS

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have no question or answere on this site; today as I was going to ask my first question I received this message on the question form:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

Is it a bug or it has a justification? I am a member of some Stackexchage websites, I am active on Programmers and StackOverflow, in the StackOverflow I have this warning too, but there I have asked many questions; But why here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have asked two questions before. Both received downvotes, and one was closed as offtopic. Both have been deleted in the meantime, but the system still "sees" them.

That said, I don't know in which way the system punishes overall behaviour on the network as a whole. Messages such as these are the result of heuristics the details of which are not necessarily public.

You get rid of the warning by asking several well-received questions (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234042/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-ban-warning)). The links the message contains lead to some hints (e.g., [this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)); you can also [check our most often used comments](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/627/reference-templates-for-common-comments) and the discussions linked in them for more specific pointers.

If you are uncertain whether a question would be suitable, feel free to drop by in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) for a "beta test".