# To Ask about how to write a best dissertation of master's is on-topic or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Topic about how to write a graduation work or master's dissertation is within the escope? is on-topic or of-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for asking!

You don't really say *what* you want to ask, but in all likelihood such a question would be

- too broad,
- [primarily opinion-based](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/979/9550), and
- offtopic if it's more about the writing than the content.

Narrowly scoped, factual questions

- about computer science parts of your theses are ontopic here, and
- about the technicalities of writing theses may be ontopic on [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

If you want to chat about which topic to choose and how to approach it, that's what you have an advisor for.
If you want to chat about things like which font may be nicer or whether it's worthwhile to learn LaTeX and/or TikZ, that's what colleagues are for.

Comment: "whether it's worthwhile to learn LaTeX and/or TikZ" -- that one's actually easy: yes.

Comment: In my case is more about script or steps of how do or where to start

Comment: @JonathasB.C., sounds too broad.   That's something you should discuss with your advisor.  We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for it this tip