# No-effort questions without an answer on cs.se

Tags: discussion, policy

Assume that I see a question that shows no effort: an easy-to-find answer (e.g. by just googling its title), or is easy to solve if a person at least made any attempt.
**But**, the question doesn't have a related answer on cs.se.
I downvote such questions and move on, but now I'm not sure what action is in line with the site's goals.
One (main?) of the goals is along the lines of "build a repository of questions and answers", and I understand it as, in particular, "if a well-formulated question is not answered on his site, then it's a valid question that should be answered".

For example, the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967580/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-string-in-python) could be found after 10 seconds of googling, so I would instantly downvote such a question. However, having such a question is considered beneficial to the SO's goal of being a library of questions and answers (and its usefulness is probably indicated by al the upvotes).

So, what's the correct action?

Comment: I wonder why there is no reaction (upvote, downvote, answer, closing, etc.) to this question.

Comment: I think there's a couple of related questions on [meta.cs.se]. FWIW, I used to post one of the [canned comments](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/751/98) di given them a _chance_ of learning what the downvotes were for. Not that most of them changed their behaviour; ignoring the posts is the only good way to not train help vampires.

Comment: @Raphael, thanks for the comment, but I think I'm talking about a bit different aspect of the situation. Consider e.g. the following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967580/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-string-in-python . The answer to this question could be found after 10 seconds of googling, so I would instantly downvote such a question. However, having such a question is considered beneficial towards the SO's goal of being a library of questions and answers (and all the upvotes speak for themselves). Hence, my confusion about what I should do.

Comment: Why would you downvote that one? It's a legitimate _question_. Unless there are policies that apply (our homework policy, maybe?) I don't think there's any reason to act, from a moderation perspective. That said, nobody can stop you from expressing your displeasure with a downvote, and you certainly have _up_vote lazy questions  All I would ask is that you only downvote with a helpful comment so the asker can learn how to improve. If you don't want to do that, better not vote at all (IMHO).